# CUDA available in notebook but not in VS code terminal - same conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, conda, stable-diffusion

I have torch installed in a conda environment. When I run python in command line and try to check CUDA availability I get False as show below.

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

However, when I use jupyter notebook, it shows CUDA is available. I'm using the same environment. The GPU is on the same local Windows machine

```py
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
> True
!which python
> /c/Users/b2bt/anaconda3/envs/stable-diffusion/python
```

I tried creating a new conda environment to run the stable diffusion web UI. I've installed torch previously in a different environment and have used it successfully with GPU. I was expecting the terminal to show CUDA available but strangely it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

This problem may be caused by using `pip install pytorch` to install package.

**Solution:**

Open [the official website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#start-locally), and search for the correct version for your environment.

[image]

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
```

Comment: I never got to try this solution but thanks for answering. 
Previously I was using the .bat file to install everything which was provided in the repository. But then I tried installing everything manually and it worked.

Comment: Thanks! I used `pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you have. I realized pytorch was not installed.

So, installed in using pip3 command stated above:

pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117